# Same record is returned while there are different records in DB?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jdbc

My code is returning object but same record multiple times because same object reference is been going through. Please suggest some modification so that i get all the records without repeating same rows.

```
DBConnection con = null;
        List<UserModel> users= new ArrayList<UserModel>();
        UserModel userModel = null;
        try {
            con = new DBConnection();
            LOGGER.info("############### DBUtils.getUsers() start");
            ResultSet rs = null;
            PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
            pstmt = con.connection.prepareStatement(
                    DBUtils.Select.USERS);
            pstmt.setString(1, user);
            pstmt.setString(2, pwd);

            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                userModel = new UserModel();
                userModel.setName(rs.getString("NAME"));
                userModel.setUserId(rs.getString("USERID"));
                userModel.setPassword(rs.getString("PASSWORD"));
                userModel.setAccountDeleted(rs.getString("ACCOUNT_DELETED"));
                userModel.setAccountEnabled(rs.getString("ACCOUNT_ENABLED"));
                userModel.setAccountExpired(rs.getString("ACCOUNT_EXPIRED"));
                userModel.setCreationTime(rs.getString("CREATION_TIME"));
                userModel.setDeletionTime(rs.getString("DELETION_TIME"));
                userModel.setCredentialsExpired(rs
                        .getString("CREDENTIALS_EXPIRED"));
                userModel.setPermissions(rs.getString("PERMISSIONS"));
                userModel.setLastLoginTime(rs.getString("LAST_LOGIN_TIME"));
                LOGGER.info("############### DBUtils.getUsers() users : "+userModel);
                users.add(userModel);
            }

            LOGGER.info("############### DBUtils.getUsers() users : "+users);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally{
            if(con!= null){
                con.closeConnection();
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you post the loggers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create instance inside loop and add it to loop, otherwise you are updating same reference and adding it to list.

```
while (rs.next()) {
            UserModel    userModel = new UserModel();
```

Comment: No, OP using same reference but pointing to different object as loop continues, so reference to previous objects will be gone.

Comment: Nambari thanks now i am getting the data and no repeated value now....previously i defined UserModel above not inside while condition...

Comment: Glad it helped, good luck! I would highly recommend you to read and understand this concept http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value